# Prevent AdMob ad from reloading when changing view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, admob, banner

I'm using AdMob, and all my view controllers use the same ad banner. However, when I change views, the entire ad reloads, cutting down my impressions. Is there a way to stop the ad from unloading or a way to share it across all view controllers? For viewcontroller.h I have

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@import GoogleMobileAds;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

__weak IBOutlet GADBannerView *bannerView;

}
```

and for viewcontroller.m the code is

```
@import GoogleMobileAds;

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

NSLog(@"Google Mobile Ads SDK version: %@", [GADRequest sdkVersion]);

self->bannerView.adUnitID = @"myadunitid";

self->bannerView.rootViewController = self;

[self->bannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

The banner class is `GADBannerview`. Is there a way to stop the ad from reloading?

Comment: I think no, Google have own algorithm for that.

Comment: it's definitely xcode and not admob. It's on multiple view controllers so it feels the need to reload every switch but it shouldn't if I knew how to implement a shared banner or singleton.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Googl AdMob Unit will refresh itself. So, we don't request to load the unit many times to avoid our account to be terminated.

Please check my proposal below in SWIFT:

- Define one static variable for GADBannerView in elsewhere.
- In one view controller: setup size and location of the GADBannerView variable
- Make sure that we will request load method once time only:

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ....................
    if (isLoaded == false)
    {
      adBannerView.load(request)
      isLoaded = true
    }
}
```

During testing, we will see that the unit will refresh itself periodically.